# waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished never returns

Tags: ios, nsoperationqueue

Can somebody please point me to the correct direction. Using an NSOperationQueue task never finishes.

This code

```
        NSOperationQueue * queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc]init];
        [queue addOperationWithBlock:^(void) {
            [self DoTextLayout]; // 1
            NSLog(@"Ended");
        }];
        [self.queue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];
        NSLog(@"Wait finished");
```

reaches successfully "Ended" but never reaches "Wait finished".

Comment: What is `self.queue`, because you never set it in that code, so you're waiting for a different queue than the one you just added an operation to...

Comment: Also, what does `doTextLayout` do? Does it dispatch anything synchronously to the main thread? If so, you could deadlock, assuming this `waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished` was done on the main thread. (BTW, do anything that could block the main thread, such as `waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished` on the main thread, is a very bad idea.)

Comment: @Wain: holy cow! How could I be so blind? It was self.queue. Codeblindness probably. Thank you!

Comment: @Rob: thank you to point that out. I am aware of the main thread issue (ie: performSelectorOnMainThread). It is not on the main thread however.